# How reference the reference in a cell, instead of the cell itself?

Tags: excel, reference

Wording of the title isn't great, I wasn't sure how to describe this so I'll use an example.

[image: Example]

In my example, cell A1 references cell C1. As written, A2 will offset from A1 and the result will be X. I want to get the result Z.

Essentially, how do I reference the actual cell that is being referenced (C1) opposed to the cell selected (A1)?

Comment: `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),2,2)),0,1)`

Comment: Or better yet:  `=INDEX(1:1,0,MATCH(A1,1:1,0)+1)`

Comment: Both of these seem to work, thanks!